# container-class is not allowed to appear in element vaadin:table

Tags: eclipse, maven, vaadin, jdal

I'm trying to run a maven project that uses vaadin and JDAL, this is it:

https://github.com/chelu/jdal-samples/tree/master/vaadin

Once I import it in Eclipse as a maven project, while building the project Eclipse displays the following error:

```
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'container-class' is not allowed to appear in element 'vaadin:table'.
```

This basically means the attribute "container-class" can not be used inside the element "vaadin:table". I did some research on the matter but didn't find much. Here is a sample of the code where an issue occures:

```
<vaadin:table entity="org.jdal.samples.model.Role" scope="prototype" 
        container-class="org.jdal.vaadin.data.ListBeanContainer">
        <vaadin:columns>
            <vaadin:column name="role" display-name="Role"/>
        </vaadin:columns>
    </vaadin:table>
```

Would anyone happen to know how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Ensure that you are using at least 2.1-RC1 version.